# How to get data from input field inside a Jquery function in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to take the input field value each time a letter is added/changed/deleted
so I'm using the jquery to trigger it.
but I don't know how to save this value.

in the html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="searchForm">
    <input id='myTextbox1' type='text'/>
  </form>
```

in the ts file:

```
searchString:string;
searchForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit(){

    this.searchForm =  new FormGroup({
      'str':new FormControl(null)
    })
    /
  

    $('#myTextbox1').on('input', function() {
    // i tried this:
      this.searchString = this.searchFrom.controls['str'].value
  });

    
  }
```

but controls weren't read from the form.

I just want to save the value of the input field in the searchstring variable and change it each time it changes.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using jquery you could update your code as below:

```
 <form [formGroup]="searchForm">
    <input id='myTextbox1' type='text' formControlName="str"/>
  </form>
```

and instead of the jquery code you could use the power of `Observables`:

```
 this.searchForm.str.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
     this.searchString = value;
 });
```